# What is Windows Runtime Type for IAsyncResult?

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I am creating a Windows Runtime component for WIndows Phone 8.1. I am calling a webservice using HttpWebRequest class. But in callback function I have to use IAsyncResult but IAsyncResult  is not valid Windows Runtime Type.

Please suggest me relevant of  IAsyncResult.

Code Block :

```
                HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(UploadServiceUrl));
                webRequest.Method = "POST";
                webRequest.ContentType = string.Format("multipart/form-data; boundary={0}", boundary);
                webRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), webRequest);

public void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
{
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
        Stream postStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult);

        writeMultipartObject(WindowsRuntimeStreamExtensions.AsOutputStream(postStream), data);
        postStream.Dispose();

        request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallback), request);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}

public void GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
{
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
        Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
        sResponse = new StreamReader(streamResponse).ReadToEnd();

        streamResponse.Dispose();
        response.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

Compile Time Error:

```
Error   2   Method 'XXXXXXX.XXXXXX.GetResponseCallback(System.IAsyncResult)' has parameter 'asynchronousResult' of type 'System.IAsyncResult'.  'System.IAsyncResult' is not a valid Windows Runtime parameter type.
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the newer pattern of just flagging the method as `async` and returning a `Task<>`?

Comment: Can you post your code and the exact compiler error? `System.IAsyncResult` is a valid .NET type (note it is unrelated to `Windows.Foundation.IAsyncAction` or `IAsyncInfo`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means you have this as a `public` method on a `public` class in a WinRT component. Just make the method `internal` and it should work.

Comment: But in that case, callback function is not called. Just for information, I have implemented "IBackgroundTask" class for background file transfers.

Comment: That's a different problem -- you likely didn't take a deferral from your Run method -- [see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.background.ibackgroundtaskinstance.getdeferral.aspx)